# Export all Site Collection Usage Reports in one click

Tags: site-collection, export, web-analytics, reports, site-usage

My manager wants me to export the every Excel and PDF file from the Site Collection Usage Reports every month. Is there a way to download or export the data in one click?

Answer (score 0):

A basic script which copy files from a library to another one or where you like, would do that, in my opinion. But you can open libraries in an Explorer.

Look [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-server-help/copy-or-move-library-files-by-using-open-with-explorer-HA101811182.aspx), and [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5a599238-cc2e-47ab-9a9f-347abd3fc5fd/how-to-export-all-files-from-a-sharepoint-site) maybe.

Depend on how many files you have to export/copy

Hope this help,

Regards,

Nico.

Comment: Thanks Nico, but the Site Collection Usage Reports are generated on the fly. I don't think they reside anywhere until someone chooses _export_.